# RedirectMatch - Stop it from matching first occurrence

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My redirects are being matched by the first occurrence and not the closest match.

Request URL: `/audios/3933`

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/audios/393/ /artists/a/1849
RedirectMatch 301 ^/audios/3933/ /artists/b/1850
```

It simply matches the first rule and it makes sense because of the `^`. However, how can I get it to match the full ID in the URL.

Please note, there is some string after the digits that I am not aware of. For example the URL can be `/audios/393/a` or `/audios/3933/a`.

How can I get this to work? I am using apache 2.4 on ubuntu.

Comment: If there is always something following the digits, you could change your rules like this: `RedirectMatch 301 "^/audios/393/.*$"  "/artists/a/1849"`.  Or if you need the string, you can do `RedirectMatch 301 "^/audios/393/(.*)$"  "/artists/a/1849/$1"`  In your question, the requested URL does not fit what you say later (*some string after the digits*...).  Usually you should put your matching rules from the most restrictive, to the more general one, top to bottom.

Comment: The `.*$` worked perfectly! Can you add this as an answer? The only tiny tiny issue is that it adds a query string to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect (and rewrite) rules should be specified with the most restrictive match first, followed by the more permissive (top down in the configuration file).

In your particular case, you mention that there is some string after the digits.  You could therefore modify your configuration like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/audios/393/.*$"  "/artists/a/1849"
RedirectMatch 301 "^/audios/3933/.*$" "/artists/b/1850"
```

If you need the string that is after the digits, use this configuration:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/audios/393/(.*)$"  "/artists/a/1849/$1"
RedirectMatch 301 "^/audios/3933/(.*)$" "/artists/b/1850/$1"
```

Where `$1` will be replaced by the string delimited by the parenthesis.  `.*` means "any character (the `.`), repeated 0 to n times (the `*`).

For the query string, `RedirectMatch` is a particular case of the `Redirect` directive.  In the `Redirect` documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect), you can read:

> This includes requests with GET parameters, such as
>   http://example.com/service/foo.pl?q=23&a=42, it will be redirected to
>   http://foo2.example.com/service/foo.pl?q=23&a=42. Note that POSTs will
>   be discarded.

So indeed, the query string is added automatically (GET).

If you do not want that, you could use `RewriteRule` instead, with flag `[QSD]` since your target URL does not contain a query string.  That flag will not add the query string to the target URL.

The configuration would then look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/audios/393/.*$"  "/artists/a/1849" [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteRule "^/audios/3933/.*$" "/artists/b/1850" [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Using parenthesis and `$1` works the same with `RewriteRule` if you need that.